# Adjusting the code to ensure the total quantity is equal to the sum of the split quantities

Tags: python

```
def generate_supplier_quantities(total_quantity, total_value, min_value, max_value, unit_rate):
    num_units = [x for x in range(1, total_quantity + 1) if min_value < x * unit_rate < max_value]
    num_values = [y * unit_rate for y in num_units]

    return num_units, num_values
```

The above code returns smaller quantities and values based on the minimum value, maximum value and unit rate.

I would like to modify the code to ensure that the total quantities are equal to the sum of `num_units` (smaller quantities) while the respective small values are still in the range of the minimum and maximum values

Here is dummy data to test the function:

`write dummy data code`

And this is the expected output for the dummy data

`Write the expected output`

Comment: What is the `total_value` parameter for? You never use it.

Comment: What are those dummy input and output? Can't you just give us one or two calls of this functin and inform what the expected output should be?

Answer (score 0):

I have implement it with sample values. You can test with your own data.

```
def generate_supplier_quantities(total_quantity, total_value, min_value, max_value, unit_rate):
    num_units = []
    num_values = []
    split_quantities = []
    current_total_quantity = 0

    for x in range(1, total_quantity + 1):
        current_value = x * unit_rate

        if min_value < current_value < max_value and current_total_quantity + x <= total_quantity:
            num_units.append(x)
            num_values.append(current_value)
            current_total_quantity += x
            split_quantities.append(current_total_quantity)


    return num_units, num_values,split_quantities

# Example usage
total_quantity = 10
total_value = 100
min_value = 5
max_value = 20
unit_rate = 2

num_units, num_values,split_quantity = generate_supplier_quantities(total_quantity, total_value, min_value, max_value, unit_rate)

print("Num Units:", num_units)
print("Num Values:", num_values)
print(f'split_quantity:{split_quantity}')
sum_split_quantity = 0
for quantity in split_quantity:
    sum_split_quantity = sum_split_quantity + quantity

print(f'total_quantity:{total_quantity}')
if sum_split_quantity == total_quantity:
    print(f'sum_split_quantity:{sum_split_quantity}=total_quantity:{total_quantity}')
```

Output: In my case

```
Num Units: [3, 4]
Num Values: [6, 8]
split_quantity:[3, 7]
total_quantity:10
sum_split_quantity:10=total_quantity:10
```